# Who is E. Kim Nebeuts?

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy, history

I just learned the name *E. Kim Nebeuts* from the quote at the beginning of Joseph O'Rourke's answer to [this question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7784/have-there-been-longitudinal-studies-comparing-outcomes-of-various-teaching-meth). Curious, I google searched. All I saw on the first 2 pages of results was things like "inspirational E. Kim Nebeuts quotes!" I am left wondering *who is/was E. Kim Nebeuts*? A math teacher, apparently, but -- where and when? And how did her / his quotes become known? Does he/she have a book? Etc.

Incidentally three quotes kept reappearing:

> To state a theorem and then to show examples of it is literally to teach backwards.
>
> A good preparation takes longer than the delivery.
>
> Teach to the problem, not to the text.

Comment: Just a wild guess: http://www.amazon.com/Michael-Stueben/e/B001KJ0GYU

Comment: Concerning Dag's brilliant guess, *E. Kim Nebeuts* is *Mike Stueben* spelled backwards. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On page 131 of *Twenty Years Before the Blackboard* by Michael Stueben, there is a quote:

> Noitaton Hsilop esrever diova! --  *E. Kim Nebeuts*

In the book there is also reference to a Mr. Loof Lirpa, so writing things backwards seems to be a recurring theme.

I think it is safe to assume E. Kim Nebeuts is Michael Stueben.